# Unclear paper status

Tags: journals

I am sorry if this question looks inappropriate here, but I have a question about the paper that I submitted to the highly ranked journal long time ago. After waiting for more than half a year I've made a status request, and I got a message from the journal secretary saying that the status is "report out with editors". Unfortunately, I have no idea what this means. The most positive interpretation is that the editors have already received the report/reports from the referee/referees and are in progress of making a decision for my paper. On the other hand, it is really not clear. I would really appreciate any help in this matter.

Comment: Which journal/publisher?

Comment: Journal of Differential Geometry, International Press

Comment: There is no information online and I can not even come up with an interpretation of the phrase "report out with editor". Sorry.

Comment: Simply ask the journal secretary for clarification.